# Whenever I try to log my facebook account in empathy I get a message saying "authentication failed"

Tags: 11.10, empathy, facebook

I'm sure my username and passwords are right. Don't know what's wrong, I could login with my google talk account. Has this happened to anyone or do you know how to solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try updating empathy or maybe your username is wrong or sometimes it just genuinely wont connect. this used to happen a lot in empathy (for me at least) i suggest copying and pasting your username from your address bar on your profile page (as empathy instructs , you use  the section after www.facebook.com/(your username is here) and entering your passwords again even if empathy is at the latest version.